# Can I partition a RAID 1 drive to replicate data that is now on multiple drives?

Tags: partitioning, backup, raid, storage, raid-1

I am getting this Western Digital RAID 1 array (https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B074R59TLB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

Currently I have data spread across three internal and one external drive. I would like to move it all to the RAID 1 box, but for the sake of my applications and organization plan, retain the existing drive letters. Can I partition the new RAID array with 3-4 partitions and assign them the current drive letters?
Thank you.

(I also regularly store full disk images off site AND use Crashplan for redundant backup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAID array is essentially a virtual drive made up of a bunch of drives,
so your operating system should see this virtual drive like it would a single drive
and create partitions as it normally would.

Your RAID array type and configuration cannot be seen by your OS.
The OS just sees the virtual drive you create with the RAID controller
and treats this virtual drive exactly the same as a physical one,
because that's what it thinks it is.
Anything you can do with a physical drive (like creating a partition)
you can do with the virtual drive you've created.

Comment: Thank you! This worked out just fine. Set the drives to RAID 1, then partitioned them, moved my old files from the old drives and renamed the partitions with the old drive letters.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer (click the V icon).

Comment: Got it, thanks. Newbie oversight. :-)